Template function accepting a pointer-to-member refuses to compile
Consider this class:
template <typename T>
struct Buffer {
    template <typename Field>
    int add_member_attribute(
            std::string&& name,
            Field T::* member_ptr)
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }  
};

struct Thing {
    int x;
    double y;
};

int main() {
    Buffer<Thing> bt;
    Buffer<float> bf;
    bt.add_member_attribute("y", &Thing::y);
}

If T is a non-class type, then the compiler complains:
buffer.h:313:22: error: member pointer refers into non-class type 'float'
            Field T::* member_ptr,
                    ^
fixture.h:78:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'Buffer<float>' requested here
        return f_real->items.data() + 32 * i;
                    ^

This is unexpected to me because no code is even trying to invoke the function when T is non-class. It seems like the error is being generated too early; why doesn't SFINAE prevent this?
Protecting add_member_attribute with a requires std::is_class_v<T> does not avoid the problem.
I've tried writing a helper class with a template specialization, including with deduction guides, in the hopes of using SFINAE to prevent the compiler from "seeing" the offending type expression:
template <typename Class, typename Field=void>
struct MemberPointer {
    template <typename U>
    MemberPointer(const U&) {} // no op
};

template <typename Class, typename Field>
requires std::is_class_v<Class>
struct MemberPointer<Class, Field> {
    using type = Field Class::*;
    
    type value;
    
    MemberPointer(type value): value(value) {}
    
    operator type() const {
        return value;
    }
};

// deduction guides
template <typename Class, typename Field>
MemberPointer(Field Class::* v) -> MemberPointer<Class, Field>;

template <typename T>
MemberPointer(T t) -> MemberPointer<T, void>;

template <typename T>
struct Buffer {
    template <typename Field>
    int add_member_attribute(
            std::string&& name,
            MemberPointer<T,Field> member_ptr)
    {
        // ...
    }  
};

Instead this prevents existing functions from matching the type:
cards.h:70:16: error: no matching member function for call to 'add_member_attribute'
        cards->add_member_attribute(PrimitiveVariable::BOUND, &Card::extents);
        ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
buffer.h:311:19: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'MemberType<Card, Field>' against 'range2 behold::Card::*'
    AttributeInfo add_member_attribute(

How do I declare this function so that it is permitted for T to be a non-class type?
(I'm using Apple Clang 15.0.)

"why doesn't SFINAE prevent this" - because you haven't SFINAE'd the function away in your top example.

[mre] please, showing how you are instantiating the template.  We're just guessing here.

@catnip, I've edited.

@TedLyngmo: Can you be more specific? What changes need to be made to the example?

template <class Field, class U = T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_class_v<U>, AttributeInfo>
add_member_attribute(AttributeKey&& name, Field U::* member_ptr) { ... } would work I think

@trbabb SFINAE either uses std::enable_if or C++20's concepts

@Pepjin and @TedLyngmo: I addressed this in my question. Using a requires statement did not fix the issue. @TedLyngmo, you'd think it would work, but it does not.

@trbabb Compiles for me in g++, clang++, MSVC and icx. demo

@TedLyngmo: Not for me in clang: https://replit.com/@tbabb/member-to-ptr-bug#main.cpp

@trbabb That's because you didn't do what I did. Note: Field U::* member_ptr not Field T::* member_ptr

@TedLyngmo: Ah.
Can you explain why this works but the requires statement does not?

You'd have to do the same trick with requires I guess. I'm not very used to concepts, but at least that works for me.

Ok. Well, that addresses the issue. Thank you!

@trbabb -- there is no type deduction in your code, how can SFINAE possibly fail? you are telling compiler to do instantiation and that one fails with hard error. You can use concepts, it's the same: https://godbolt.org/z/h7Pn5WP4x

@trbabb -- another thing you can do is to provide a partial specialization for non-class type, like this: https://godbolt.org/z/316sqcaeq

SFINAE only applies in immediate context. See dupe What exactly is the "immediate context" mentioned in the C++11 Standard for which SFINAE applies?.

SFINAE applies to "direct" context, here
template <typename T>
struct Buffer {
    template <typename Field>
    int add_member_attribute(
            std::string&& name,
            Field T::* member_ptr)
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }  
};

T is already fixed, and so
template <typename Field>
int add_member_attribute(
        std::string&& name,
        Field float::* member_ptr) // WRONG
{
    // ...
    return 0;
}  

is wrong for any Field.
As often, extra indirection helps:
template <typename T>
struct Buffer {
    template <typename Field,
              typename U = T, // To allow SFINAE
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, U>, bool> = false> // Enforce that U == T
    int add_member_attribute(
            std::string&& name,
            Field U::* member_ptr)
    {
        // ...
        return 0;
    }  
};


Thanks for this!  I understood the problem, but didn't consider the indirection hack shown here.

This is clarifying; thank you. In my mental model, any template object— including a template member function— isn't defined / "doesn't exist" until it's instantiated, and substitution only happens then. It sounds like there are "stages" of substitution, which is a subtle point I was not aware of!
